# GBM cross validation

Tags: r, cross-validation, gbm

I'm trying to use `R`'s `gbm` regression model.
I want to compute the coefficient of determination (R squared) between the cross validation predicted response values and the true response values. However, the `cv.fitted` values of the `gbm.object` only provides the predicted response values for 1-`train.fraction`. So in order to get what I want I need to find which of the observations correspond to the `cv.fitted` values.

Any idea how to get that information?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the predict function to easily get at model predictions, if I'm understanding your question correctly.

```
dat <- data.frame(y = runif(1000), x=rnorm(1000))

gbmMod <- gbm::gbm(y~x, data=dat, n.trees=5000, cv.folds=0)

summary(lm(predict(gbmMod, n.trees=5000) ~ dat$y))$adj.r.squared
```

But shouldn't we hold data to the side and assess model accuracy on test data? This would correspond to the following, where I partition the data into a training set (70%) and testing set (30%):

```
inds <- sample(1:nrow(dat), 0.7*nrow(dat))

train <- dat[inds, ]
test <- dat[-inds, ]

gbmMod2 <- gbm::gbm(y~x, data=train, n.trees=5000)

preds <- predict(gbmMod2, newdata = test, n.trees=5000)

summary(lm(preds ~ test[,1]))$adj.r.squared
```

It's also worth noting that the number of trees in the `gbm` can be tuned using the `gbm.perf` function and the `cv.folds` argument to the `gbm` function. This helps avoids overfitting.